# How can I put a ReactJS-bootstrap form and h1 tag side by side

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I want to place my FormGroup and my h1 tag side-by-side horizontally. I've tried using display: inline-block and various other stuff but no luck. Here's my .css code:

```
.testingForm {
  max-width: 320px;
}

.testingMore {
  text-align: left;
  float: right;
}
```

And here's the .js code:

```
<div className="testingForm">
  <FormGroup
    controlId="stuff"
    bsSize="large"
  >
    <ControlLabel>Stuff</ControlLabel>
    <FormControl
    />
  </FormGroup>
</div>
<div className="testingMore">
  <h1>Additional Stuff</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an element that wraps both your form and header, and make it into a `flex` container with `display:flex;`

```css
.form-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.testingForm {
  max-width: 320px;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <div className="testingForm">
    <form>
      Test: <input type="text"/>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Additional Stuff</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```